# How to make width of absolutely positioned div same as its parent div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display an absolutely positioned div inside floating div.
Here is my HTML so far.

```
#outer
{ 
    float:left;
    width:500px; 
    border: 1px solid red; 

}

#inner
{
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:100%
}


<div id='outer'>
    <div id='inner'>
        some text inside div
    </div>
</div>
```

I have an outer div whose width is being set as percentage of its parent div. 'outer' div contains an absolutely positioned 'inner' div. 
I want to make width of the inner div same as outer div which is not working. Can somebody suggest a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `position: relative` on floated div and `width: 100%` on inner div?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give `position:relative;` to your `#outer` div. write like this

```
#outer
{ 
    float:left;
    width:500px; 
    border: 1px solid red; 
    position:relative
}
```

check this http://jsbin.com/ifuxum/2/edit#html,live

Comment: yeah. it does work. Thanks :) Can you explain how does it solve the issue?

Comment: Read this article for better understanding http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: I noticed that the height of outer div is not increasing with increase in height of inner div? Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: you can do two things first remove position:absolute from your inner div & second you can use javascript for that.

Answer (score 2):

```
#inner
{
    left:0;
    right:0;
    position:absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```